# Windows 10 Display Language Refusing to Change

Tags: windows-10, language

I'm using Windows 10 Professional. When I initially installed it, I chose German, and I want to change the display language to English instead. That includes right-click menus, Explorer, etc.

I've tried the following settings:

Under Region and Language, I have removed everything but English (US) and made sure it's set as the default:

[image: Image of settings]

Under Control Panel > Language, it also only says English (US):

[image: Image of settings].

In that same menu, under options, it says that no language pack is available:

[image: that no language pack is available].

I have also tried all of the above with English (UK) instead of English (US), didn't work either. I've rebooted between changes to no avail.

Comment: I went through this a few years ago. Tried multiple things on windows settings which only partially solved the problem. Then I found the solution, essentially the idea was to run the windows installation again, so we go through the language selection menu. But not rebooting or using the ISO, just staring it from cmd. Unfortunately I don't remember the command. And will appreciate very much if one can add it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, found a solution.

I downloaded the language pack from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14236/language-packs and installed it with `lpksetup.exe` which comes with windows. Now my system is fully translated.

Comment: You can accept your own answer: click on the check mark beside the answer.

Comment: while i have done this as well some time ago, some apps dont start with the default/top most language. Particularly this is the explorer process that hosts the taskbar and the `win+r` run popup, which is soooo annoying. I have the feeling that they get initialized before the setting is read.

Answer (score -1):

To me it didnt work.

But here's how i successfully made it:

1. Use the **Windows key + I** keyboard shortcut to open the Settings app.
2. Click **Time & language**.

   [image]
3. Click **Region & language**.
4. Under Languages, click **Add a language**.
5. Click the language you want to add, and select the specific
   variation if applicable.
6. Select the new language and click **Options** (and download any the
   language packs as necessary).
7. On Region & language, select the new language, and click **Set as
   default** (if it isnt set allready).
8. Make **Restart** and boom- the display language is on.

Enjoy!